# How do I read something from stdin in gforth and store it in a variable?

Tags: forth

I've tried the following code after reading the docs:

```
   create buff 128 allot
   buff 128 stdin read-line throw
```

I was hoping that this would get me a char for each successive address of buff, but I'm getting this weird number in there:

```
buff @  ok
. 3689349013085184353  ok
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What was in stdin? Was it beginning with `aaaaa333` by any chance?

Comment: Have you tried something like `buff count type`?

Comment: I think it was aaaaa something. What am I missing here lol???

Comment: Oh, it seems that I misunderstood how strings work with ANS Forth implementations. Although, in my tests, COUNT is returning the wrong length of the string (I type like 6 chars and it gives me something like 97!!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`buff` put the address of your `buff` variable on the (data) stack. The memory by that address contained the input received from `stdin`, something like this:

```
Address  Value
-------  -----
N+0      0x61
N+1      0x61
N+2      0x61
N+3      0x61
N+4      0x61
N+5      0x33
N+6      0x33
N+7      0x33
...      ...
```

The `@` word transformed the address left by `buff` into an integer value by that address. But since you've (apparently) got a 64-bit `gforth` version, `@` returned a 64-bit, i.e. 8-byte, value starting at the given address, i.e. `0x3333336161616161`, which is `3689349013085184353` in decimal. The `.` word just showed you that number.

If you want to fetch a particular *byte*, use `c@` instead of `@`:

```
buff c@ .
```

That'll give you the code of the first character in the buffer (`0x61` or `97`). If you want to get the second item, increment the address before executing `c@`, like this:

```
buff 1+ c@ .
```

Similarly, this will get you the sixth character's code:

```
buff 5 + c@ .
```